# Joining Taxonomies in an Ubercart Views into a single Field Group (D6)

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, ubercart

I have a view for a taxonomy term filtered by the argument.

A particular product has more than one taxonomy term related to the individual node.

This works for only all nodes that have just one taxonomy term. Unfortunately i have a product that has more than one taxonomy term.

Thus on the page with that particular product I have them grouped by fields. When i do this they're displayed as two different fields. All the products with a singular term and another taxonomy term with two terms.

Is there a way for me to group the node into one field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding "Term" as a field.

Then grouping terms by the field "Term" and not "All Taxonomy Terms"